# Unable to hit Spring Controller from angular js using jsonp request

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, jsonp

I am trying to implement integration of Spring with Angular js. I am making a jsonp request from my js file .But I am getting an error which itself is not clear. I tried using post request but it was giving CORS error which was expected and I want to avoid extra overhead so decided to continue with jsonp.
I hit-and try using https also but it is giving SSL protocol error which was  also expected. But I dont know what is the error occuring here.

services.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('UserService', ['$http', function($http){
return{
    createUser: function(user){

        var url="http://localhost:8083/HCP_Android_Demo/user?user="+user+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
        return $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

UserController.js

```
@Controller
 public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String index() {
    return "Login";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/user",method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})    
@ResponseBody
public void createUser(@RequestParam("user") User user,@RequestParam("callback") String callBackFunction){
    System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getUsername());

}
```

Error on console

```
angular.js:10573 GET http://localhost:8083/HCP_Android_Demo/user?user=[object%20Object]&callback=angular.callbacks._0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send an object as the url param. You can either use POST and send object or convert your user to be a string if that works for you

Comment: Thanx a lot..!! It worked. I want to make post request here so as to use hibernate on another side to save user details easily but I was not able to handle CORS error that's why I opt JSONP.